# Apache: .htaccess: SEO: how to eliminate query string syntax (PHP)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp

Excellent help for my question is provided in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained). However, despite trying things as described therein I am still having problems because it seems as though my [.htaccess file is not being parsed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427815/xampp-htaccess-mod-rewrite-not-working).

I have a website which consists of the following pages:

```
http://mywebsite.com/?menu1=home
http://mywebsite.com/?menu1=posts&menu2=johndoe
http://mywebsite.com/?menu1=posts&menu2=janedoe
http://mywebsite.com/?menu1=posts&menu2=nickdoe
http://mywebsite.com/?menu1=fashion&menu2=armani
http://mywebsite.com/?menu1=fashion&menu2=gucci
http://mywebsite.com/?menu1=about
```

The pages are displayed through the default `index.php` file in my `xampp` directory on Windows.

What would it take to have the browser respond to the following SEO frienly links instead? I would like to have my PHP code work with at least modifications as possible.

```
http://mywebsite.com/home
http://mywebsite.com/posts/johndoe
http://mywebsite.com/posts/janedoe
http://mywebsite.com/posts/nickdoe
http://mywebsite.com/fashion/armani
http://mywebsite.com/fashion/gucci
http://mywebsite.com/about
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these rules in your Root/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /?menu1=$1&menu2=$2 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /?menu1=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

The first rule rewrites "/posts/jondoe/" to "/?menu=posts&menu=jonde" and the second rule rewrites "/about" to "/?home=about"..

Comment: **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d** tells apache to stop rewriting if the request is already for an existing directory (if you request a directory http://example.com/dir , then apache will not rewrite your request but it will serve you the directory you requested)

Comment: **RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f** tells apache to stop rewriting if the request is already for an existing file (if you request an existing http://example.com/foo.php , then apache will not rewrite your request but it will serve you the file you requested)

Comment: You can find more information about Url rewriting ,flags on Apache's official documentation http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: OK, now I get it, the paths specified on the right-hand-side of the rewrite rules are absolute paths, so everything will be relative to `http://mywebsite.com/`. If these paths need to be relative to the directory .htaccess is found in, then make the paths relative.