# .htaccess created or modified: do I have to restart Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I am trying to debug some .htaccess problems on Apache but I am new to mod_rewrite.c. I would like to know whether I need to restart Apache in XAMPP whenever I make modifications to the .htaccess files, or whether these are parsed and applied whenever a web page is served independently of whether Apache is restarted.

Comment: A restart is needed when editing the central configuration but not .htaccess files. Those are parsed on the fly. Not putting it as an answer because I don't readily know an official source for confirmation

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am trying to get mod_rewrite to work. Do I have to modify the `<Directory />` section of the *central configuration file* `C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf` and restart, or is it enough that `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">` is looking OK. I am having [this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32427815/xampp-htaccess-mod-rewrite-not-working) at the moment. Do you think you can help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A restart is **not** required for changes to .htaccess.   Something else is wrong.

Make sure your .htaccess includes the statement

> RewriteEngine on

which is required even if it's also present in httpd.conf.  Also check that .htaccess is readable by the httpd process.
Check the error_log - it will tell you of any errors in .htaccess *if* it's being used.
Putting an intentional syntax error in .htaccess is a good check to make sure the file is being used -- you should get a 500 error on any page in the same directory.

Lastly, you can enable a rewrite log using commands like the following in your httpd.conf:

> RewriteLog "logs/rewritelog"
>
> RewriteLogLevel 7

The log file thus generated will give you the gory detail of which rewrite rules matched and how they were handled.

[Do you have to restart apache to make re-write rules in the .htaccess take effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142559/do-you-have-to-restart-apache-to-make-re-write-rules-in-the-htaccess-take-effec)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Not only does it answer my question but it also provides invaluable insight on how to debug a .htaccess file. Thanks.